# Given a directed weighted graph with self loops ,find the list of nodes that are exactly k dist from a given node x?

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming, cycle

Each edge in the graph has weight of 1,The graph may have cycles ,if a node has self loop it can be any distance from itself from 0 to infinity , depending on the no. of time we take the self loop.

I have solved the problem using bfs, but the constraint on distance is in order of 10^9 ,hence bfs is slow.

We ll be asked multiple queries on a given graph of the form
(distance , source)
and the o/p is the list of nodes that are exactly at the given distance starting from the source vertex.

**Constraints**

```
1<=Nodes<=500
1<queries<=500
1<=distance<=10^9
```

I have a feeling ,there would be many repeated computations as the no. of nodes are small,but i am not able to figure out how do i reduce the problem in smaller problems.

What is the efficient way to do this?

Edit : I have tried using matrix exponentiation but its too slow ,for the given constraints. The problem has a time limit of 1 sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `G = (V,E)` be your graph, and define the adjacency matrix `A` as follows:

```
A[i][j] = 1       (V[i],V[j]) is in E
          0       otherwise
```

In this matrix, for each `k`:

```
(A^k)[i][j] > 0 if and only if there is a path from v[i] to v[j] of length exactly k.
```

This means by creating this matrix and then calculating the exponent, you can easily get your answer.

For fast exponent calculation you can use [exponent by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), which will yield `O(M(n)^log(k))` where `M(n)` is the [cost for matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Algorithms_for_efficient_matrix_multiplication) for nXn matrix.

This will also save you some calculation when looking for different queries on the same graph.

**Appendix - claim proof:**

Base: `A^1 = A`, and indeed in `A` by definition, `A[i][j]=1` if and only if `(V[i],V[j])` is in `E`

Hypothesis: assume the claim is correct for all `l<k`

`A^k = A^(k-1)*A`. From induction hypothesis, `A^(k-1)[i][j] > 0` iff there is a path of length `k-1` from `V[i]` to `V[j]`.

Let's examine two vertices `v1,v2` with indices `i` and `j`.

If there is a path of length `k` between them, let it be `v1->...->u->v2`. Let the index of `u` be `m`.

From i.h. `A^(k-1)[i][m] > 0` because there is a path. In addition `A[m][j] = 1`, because `(u,v2) = (V[m],V[j])` is an edge.

```
A^k[i][j] = A^(k-1)*A[i][j] = A^(k-1)[i][1]A[1][j] + ... + A^(k-1)[i][m]A[m][j] + ... + A^(k-1)[i][n]A[n][j]
```

And since `A[m][j] > 0` and `A^(k-1)[i][m] > 0`, then `A^(k-1)*A[i][j] > 0`

If there is no such path, then for each vertex `u` such that (u,v2) is an edge, there is no path of length `k-1` from `v` to `u` (otherweise `v1->..->u->v2` is a path of length `k`).

Then, using induction hypothesis we know that if `A^(k-1)[i][m] > 0` then `A[m][j] = 0`, for all `m`.

If we assign that in the sum defining `A^k[i][j]`, we get that `A^k[i][j] = 0`

**QED**

Small note: Technically, `A^k[i][j]` is the number of paths between `i` and `j` of length exactly `k`. This can be proven similar to above but with a bit more attention to details.

To avoid the numbers growing too fast (which will increase `M(n)` because you might need big integers to store that value), and since you don't care for the value other than 0/1 - you can treat the matrix as booleans - using only 0/1 values and trimming anything else.

Comment: For small k and large n, the naive BFS approach will be cheaper. Otherwise, this is the way to go.

Comment: Though your approach is correct , it is too slow for 500 queries on matrix of 500x500 to the power 10^9 . The time limit for the original problem is 1 second.

Comment: I solved it with your approach + [faster multiplication for boolean matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_Four_Russians)

Answer (score -1):

if there are cycles in your graph, then you can infer that there is a link between each adjacent nodes in `cycle * N + 1`, because you can iterate through as much as you wish.

That bring me to the idea, we can use the cycles to our advantage!
using BFS while detecting a cycle, we calculate `offset + cycle*N` and then we get as close to our goal(K)

and search for the K pretty easily.

e.g.

A -> B -> C -> D -> B 
K = 1000;
S = A;

A - 0
B - 1
C - 2
D - 3
B - 1 (+ 4N)
here you can check floor() of `k - (1+4N) = 0` > `1000 - 1 - 4N = 0` > `999 = 4N` > `N=249` => best B is `249*4 + 1` = `997`
simpler way would be to calculate: `round(k - offset, cycle)`

from here you can count only few more steps.
in this example (as a REGEX): `A(BCD){249}BCD`